# How to publish own OpenERP modules in Launchpad?

Tags: bazaar, odoo, launchpad

I developed a couple of modules for OpenERP and want to make them available to others.
The obvious VCS choice is Launchpad (even if I feel tempted to use GitHub).

I have a development environment with all these modules, but people should be able to download/branch only the ones they want. As you may know, each a module is a separate folder inside de `addons` project folder.

Should I:

- ...create a branch of `lp:openobject-addons` for each module? That seems to generate a lot of duplicate files in my dev machine. And will people be able to extract only my module from the full branch?
- ... create an empty "host" Project and then a branch for each module? Does this follow best practices? Will this make it difficult for people to download a few, or all, of the modules?
- .. or do something else I'm not considering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a separate project and branch for each of the modules is probably the most sensible thing to do.

This allows people to check out just those projects they care about, and submit changes for just the projects they care about. The overhead of creating a new projects is pretty low.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to publish your modules to the [OpenERP Apps site](http://apps.openerp.com/), you don't want to create a branch of `lp:openobject-addons`. The [page for registering a branch](http://apps.openerp.com/send_branch/) specifically says not to do that.

Other than that, your choice seems to be between one branch per module, or several modules within a single project, each in its own subfolder. Personally, I would lean towards the second option because you don't have to create and register a new branch every time. Customers can download each module independently as a zip file from the apps site, or download the whole branch directly from Launchpad.

Note that this just covers your own modules. If you want to submit bug fixes to the core modules, see [this question on merge proposals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2121225/4794).